# Coffee script doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Today i tried coffee script (what a funny name xD),but it doesn't work properly.
My script is:

```
add=(a,b)-> a + b
add 2,2
```

and it returned this:

```
(function() {
var add;

add = function(a, b) {
return a + b;
};

add(2, 2);

}).call(this);
```

This structure of function isn't built properly in my opinion.It begin with a function,and in a function insert another one?And the variable declared in the function are superflue,they work only in the function.And this line:

```
 .call(this)
```

what mean?
Someone can help me to fix this issue of coffee script please?

Comment: It is just wrapping your code inside a [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @gillesc: You meant IIFE, not closure

Comment: @Bergi No I meant closure, just to annoy the IIFE pedants :)

Comment: What can i do now?How it work?

Comment: @GiovanniGiordano: It *does* work. What do you think would need to be done? What result did you expect? Did you check the duplicate?

Comment: @gillesc: Not going to start an argument over [what is a closure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30252701/1048572) here, but in this case a link to [module IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092101/what-is-this-javascript-pattern-called-and-why-is-it-used) would've helped the OP more than the term "closure"

Comment: And now if i want to call my Function,how can i do this?I rapid example please?