# AMD - Building library example

Tags: javascript, jquery, amd

It was suggested that I read on **AMD** and maybe rethink my library setup. For the moment I've coded all of it the **IIFE** way, hiding all the small components from the *global scope*.

But when I saw how easy it is to just `define()` things in **AMD**, I wanted to try it out!

But I ran into a couple of problems and I can't seem to understand **where it starts and how things are loaded in**. Now, be aware that I've read a lot on the subject and I searched for answers, but I think **it's more a misconception on my part** that blocks me from understanding what I read haha.

So I will ask as I understand it! :)

---

So let's start with a simple example ( by the way I don't want to create a nodeJS module, but a standard library for websites ), let's say I have this code :

```js
//----------------------------------------------
// main.js
//----------------------------------------------

var myLib = {}

//----------------------------------------------
// hello.js
//----------------------------------------------

myLib.hello = function() { console.log("hello"); }

//----------------------------------------------
// bye.js
//----------------------------------------------

myLib.bye = function() { console.log("bye"); }
```

I would like to turn it into something like :

```js
//----------------------------------------------
// main.js
//----------------------------------------------

define("myLib", ["hello". "bye"], function( hello, bye ){
    return {
        hello: hello,
        bye: bye
    };
});

//----------------------------------------------
// hello.js
//----------------------------------------------

define(function(){
    return function() { console.log("hello"); 
})

//----------------------------------------------
// bye.js
//----------------------------------------------

define(function() { 
    return function() { console.log("bye"); }
});
```

---

### Questions

1. How do I attach `myLib` to the window object ( [what I found](https://gist.github.com/CrocoDillon/9990078) ) ? Can you please provide me an example that works with `myLib` ?
2. What happens in the HTML? How many script tags do I need to make this work? One : `<script ... scr="loadMyLib.js"></script>` ?
3. As I understood, I need requireJS as a dependency when working the AMD way, right?
4. Is there something wrong with how I see all of this? I'm thinking maybe AMD is meant only for nodeJS maybe?

### Why change to AMD?

For many reasons:

- I don't have to write each time `(function(){...})()`.
- No more script tags in the HTML ( well just one, the library...and the dependencies ).
- More simple :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it down. Here is how I did :

---

> 1. Download [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html).
>
> As I understood, **AMD** is a specification for the programming
>   language JavaScript. It defines an application programming interface
>   (API) that defines code modules and their dependencies, and loads them
>   asynchronously if desired. - *Wikipedia*
>
> **RequireJS** implements **AMD**.

---

> 2. Create your **project setup**.

Let's create the following project :

```
./
|-- js
|   |-- lib
|   |   |-- jquery.js
|   |   |-- babana.js   // Whatever that is.
|   |   |-- require.js  // requireJS (YES).
|   |
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- methods
|   |   |   |-- hello.js
|   |   |   |-- bye.js
|   |   |
|   |   |-- core.js     // Core of our library.
|   |
|   |-- app.js  // Important
|
|-- index.html
```

---

> 3. Create your **index.html** file and insert the **requireJS** script like so :

```html
<script data-main="js/app" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

There are some important things going on here :

1. Well, you must load the **require.js** library.
2. You must specify the **source file** of your project in the `data-main` attribute. See this file as the entry point to your library's code. In this case: **app.js**.

This can seem confusing as of how it all comes together, but no worries, we are getting there soon enough. :)

---

> 4. Set **requireJS** *configurations* and **require** our library.

You remember how we specified the **source file** in the `data-main` attribute of the script tag? Let's add all we need in there :

```
//------------------------------
// js/app.js
//------------------------------

// Config
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/src',
    paths: {
        pixi: '../lib/pixi',
        jquery: '../lib/jquery',
        banana: '../lib/banana'
    }
});

// Load our library.
requirejs(['core'], function( MyLib) {

    // Set it to the global scope.
    window.MyLib = MyLib;

});
```

There is a lot going on, so I'll provide some explanations.

### requirejs.config

- **baseUrl**: Every time we want to load/require a js file, it will search for the desired file starting at the url we specify here. In our case, we set it to `js/src` as most of our files are located there.
- **paths**: You can manually set all the paths here if you want. A good idea is to set the external libraries here, as you may request them in your library. *Also notice* how you have to write `../`, this is because it starts from the `baseUrl`.

### requirejs( array?, function )

- **array** (optional): This is your *request* array. You insert all the js files you want to be loaded in this array. *Notice that* to use a loaded **function or object**, you need to set a parameter in the function next to it. Here we load `core` and the parameter that provides it is `myLib`.
- **function**: This is the *action function*. Here you put the code be executed. **It is important** at some point in your program to export your library to the global scope: **window**.

> 5. Define the `core` and the rest of your library.

There is, of course, a lot of ways to create your library structure. This is one way of doing it. Check [jQuery's setup](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) for some inspirations.

```
//------------------------------
// js/src/core.js
//------------------------------

define( [
    "./methods/hello",
    "./methods/bye"
], function( hello, bye ) {

"use strict";

var 
    version = "1.0",
    MyLib = function() { }; // Define a local copy of MyLib

MyLib.fn = MyLib.prototype = {
    constructor: MyLib, 

    // Loaded functions
    hello: hello,
    bye: bye
};

return MyLib;

});


//------------------------------
// js/src/methods/hello.js
//------------------------------

define( function() {
    return function() {
        console.log("hello");
    };
} );


//------------------------------
// js/src/methods/bye.js
//------------------------------

define( function() {
    return function() {
        console.log("bye");
    };
} );
```

Well, I won't explain how all of this works together, because this answer is already to long haha. But you get the idea.

---

> 6. Use your library in the browser!

Your library should now be available like so :

`MyLib.fn.hello()` or `MyLib.fn.bye()`.