# Trouble understanding syntax of nested function in constant declaration, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, nested, brackets

in the following example of functions inside a constant I don't understand the presence of the two sets of round brackets, one containing the main function and the second one just on its own at line 5

```
 1  const increment = (function () {
 2    return function increment (number, value) {
 3       return number + value;
 4    };
 5  })();
 6  console.log(increment(5,2));
```

Getting rid of the brackets will not give an error but will print this instead of the result

```
ƒ increment (number, value) {
        return number + value;
}
```

I tried using just one plain function instead (as opposed to nested ones) and as expected no brackets were needed,

Finally, thinking that maybe the sets of brackets somehow needed to match the number or arguments of the nested function, I tried a similar constant declaration but with three arguments to see whether I needed as many sets of brackets to go with it (example below) but as it turns out it only needed the same brackets as in the original bit.

```
const sum = (function () { 
    return function sum1(a,b,c)  { return a + b + c};
})();
console.log (sum(1,2,3));
```

Not sure whether I've missed something obvious or there are syntax rules I'm not aware of.
Either way, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Since you're asking about javascript, you should use the 'javascript' tag.

Comment: Fair point @PaulDempsey, fixed

Comment: "*maybe the sets of brackets somehow needed to match the number or arguments of the nested function*" - no, the need to match the number of argument of the outer function.

Comment: "*I tried using just one plain function instead (as opposed to nested ones) and as expected no brackets were needed*" - yes, the nesting is really pointless here. Where did you get this example from?

Comment: @Bergi  I got it from this video at about 2:53:30                              https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkZNo7MFNFg                                                                                                                       Yes the nesting is pointless as it's just functional to something that is shown later in the video.                                                                                                          
It's just frustrating not understanding the logic behind those round brackets. It does not work without them    
 Thank you for your replies by the way

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092101/what-is-this-javascript-pattern-called-and-why-is-it-used

Comment: @PaulDempsey it already is closed as a duplicate of that question…